# How many magazines?

Tags: logical-deduction, mathematics

You would like to sort some monthly magazines in different categories.

Disregarding the title of magazines, there are 4 different categories if you arrange magazines by publishing year and month.

Disregarding the publishing year, there are 5 different categories if you sort magazines by title and month.

Disregarding month, you could divide magazines in to  6 different categories if you sort magazines by title and publishing year.

How many monthly magazines you have *at most*?

There is no magazine with the same title, publishing year and month. Each categorization does not need to have the same number of magazines.

Comment: Sorry. I added "at most" to the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

10 mayhaps?

[image]

The picture corresponds with the magazines in the natural way. Projections along the three axes have sizes 4, 5, and 6.

I conjecture that with $a$, $b$, and $c$ categories in the three axes, the maximum number of magazines is at most $\sqrt{abc}$.

Comment: I like the visualization.

Comment: Stunning visualization, requires hardly any explanation. On the conjecture, you probably mean "With $a$, $b$, and $c$ categories in the **projections along** the three axes, the maximum number of magazines is at most $\sqrt{abc}$."?

Comment: I like it, too. As Lopsy conjectured, the number of magazines is at most $\sqrt{abc}$. This was the problem #5 in International Math. Olympiad 1992.

Comment: I conjecture that with $D$ classifiers, and $a_1$, $a_2$, .. , $a_D$ categories for each of the cases in which one classifier is ignored, the number of magazines is at most $(a_1 a_2 .. a_D)^{1/(D-1)}$.

Answer (score 1):

Welp, looks like I can max out at 10 mags:

```
a 2000 jan
b 2000 jan
c 2000 jan
a 2001 jan
b 2001 jan
c 2001 jan
a 2000 feb
b 2000 feb
a 2001 feb
b 2001 feb
```

**Old:**
I think 6 would be the number of magazines.

```
a 2000 Jan  or  a 2000 Jan
b 2000 Feb      b 2000 Feb
c 2000 Jan      c 2000 Mar
d 2000 Feb      d 2000 Jan
a 2001 Jan      e 2000 Jan
b 2001 May      a 2001 Jan
```

Any repeating combo of attributes would increase one of the other groups.

We have to cross over 2 years, since one year with the #6 means you'd need 6 different mags, which would completely bork #5, which directly says we have a repeating title-month.

We have to have 2 repeating year-month combos, and one repeating title-month combo, which are mutually exclusive.  So, that means we have at most 3 distinct months. We can achieve the 4 year-month combos with 2 years and 2 months if desired.

So what about a repeating title-year? Well, that would increase the title-month count, so we can't have that. So, 6 magazines.

Comment: You can do it with only 2 months. In your second example you can have `c 2001 Feb` instead of `c 2000 Mar` and still meet all the criteria.

Comment: That would reduce the year-month count to 3.

Comment: Nope, you still have Jan 2000, Feb 2000, Jan 2001, and Feb 2001.

Comment: Ah, right. I'll adjust that.